# Spring Boot websocket RabbitMQ STOMP relay broker cannot send message when sent from instance without TCP connection to client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I've got this issue when I try to send websocket message from the instance that has no TCP connection to client.

My setup:
2 instances of spring boot app. Single external RabbitMQ broker.

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/", "/queue/", "/exchange/")
            .setRelayHost(properties.getRelayHost())
            .setRelayPort(properties.getRelayPort())
            .setSystemLogin(properties.getRelaySystemLogin())
            .setSystemPasscode(properties.getRelaySystemPassword())
            .setClientLogin(properties.getRelayClientLogin())
            .setClientPasscode(properties.getRelayClientPassword())
            .setUserDestinationBroadcast(properties.getUserDestinationBroadcast())
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast(properties.getUserRegistryBroadcast());
    }
```

Client connected to instance-1, messages sent from instance-1 are sent to client correctly.
When message is sent from instance-2 I get the user session from `SimpUserRegistry`, but sending message fails with: `No TCP connection for session ...`
Am I doing something wrong here or what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have solution yet?

Comment: We did a crazy workaround that every time we wanted to send websocket we send message to topic and all instances of our backend would take the message from their consumer group and try to process it

Comment: It works for me now, I miss some configuration, I just post as answer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some configuration

```
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
            .setAutoStartup(Boolean.TRUE)
            .setClientLogin(username)
            .setClientPasscode(password)
            .setSystemLogin(username)
            .setSystemPasscode(password)
            .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved.user.dest")
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/registry.broadcast")
            .setRelayHost(relayHost)
            .setRelayPort(relayPort);
```

Just adding 2 more configuration properties, It works perfectly for me, no need to work around

```
 .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved.user.dest")
 .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/registry.broadcast")
```

Comment: Awesome！I don't to need to customize DefaultUserDestinationResolver anymore!